# LaTeX Image Placement

Tags: graphics

I am extremely new to LaTeX so this question will definitely make me look like a newbie.

I'm attempting to put in two images into a report. The first one was placed exactly where I wanted it and it looks good. The second image does not fit onto the page and so it vectors it onto the next (which is completely fine). The issue is that it automatically places the image into the middle of the next page, which I don't want. I would like it to be at the top of the page.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/CvsT.png}
\caption{C vs. T}
\label{fig:inputs}
\end{figure}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-vertposfp

Comment: Does the apply to Overleaf?

Comment: did you try? If yes, what was the problem?

Comment: Managed to play around with the width to give a satisfactory result.

Comment: Please show all of your code, not just the figure.

Comment: note by using `[hbt!]` you are explicitly preventing the figure being placed on a page on its own (the layout you finally got) and so it is very likely to drift to the end of the document and then be forced on to a float page with `\clearpage`.  You should almost always include `p` if you use the option (and only use `!` in exceptional cases where you want to over-ride the typesetting constraints)